# Multiple imports in python as the same keyword

Tags: python, django, import, internationalization, python-import

I am more or less a python noob and while getting my hands dirty, in one of the modules I am using, I encountered this statement:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _`

The statement is django and i18n related, but the question is of a more general nature... I think. So, if I use `_("some string to be translated")` in my code, which one is the function called, ugettext or ugettext_lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma divides up clauses of the import statement.  That code is equivalent to:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: Thanks for the short and clear answer to a newbie question, and finally... I can vote up too :P